# Mongoose: Find all tags for a specific set of articles

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema articleSchema:

```
{
    //other attributes
    tags : [ String ]
}
```

I want to search for articles based on a certain criteria and retrieve only the tags, and then create a single array of the tags from all the articles without duplicates.

Is there any built in functionality in mondgodb and mongoose of doing this?

Comment: Where are your attempts? What didn't work?

Comment: I rephrased my question. I can certainly make this work but I wonder if there is a standard build in way of doing this that doesn't require me to search myself and aggregate the results.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/

Comment: @WiredPrairie Awesome! Write as a reply to the question and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by WiredPrairie, `distinct` was the solution.

```
var query = { /** Query for the articles that I want tags from */ };

//Using mongoose-q
return Article.distinctQ('tags', query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
  db.getCollection('collection').find({'your query'}).distinct('tags', function(err, results){
              console.log(results);
  });
```